# change height on an element with the height on another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying that a div takes the height of another one when mouse enter but `jQuery(this)` doesn't work.

I've the following code:

```js
jQuery(".laynav.primary ul li").mouseenter(function(){
   jQuery(".navbar").css('height', '350px');
});
jQuery(".laynav.primary ul li").mouseleave(function(){
   jQuery(".navbar").css('height', '60px');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I want to change `jQuery(".navbar").css('height', '350px');` for `$(this).ul` height's but i don't know how.

If i put `.laynav.primary ul li ul` directly in the `.css` it's been applied everywhere and i only want it in the ones that's being hovered.

Thanks

Comment: `$(".navbar").css('height', $("ul", this).css("height"));`

Comment: Love you dude!! And is there any chance to add a $("ul", this).css("height") + 60px ? Thanks!!!

Comment: First do: `var newHeight = (parseInt($("ul", this).css("height")) + 60) + "px";`

Comment: Then do: `$(".navbar").css('height', newHeight);`

Comment: Y'all gotta make it an answer so we can upvote it.